# UploadFile using React Native as Frontend and FastAPI as backend on heroku

Tags: python, react-native, heroku, fastapi

I wanted to upload file as input for FASTapi to process it. I tried running it in swagger and it works. However, I tried calling the api from my react native app in the phone but i can't seem to do it. I have been getting bad request error and I am not sure what should I passed as body or if the way I am calling is even correct since this is my first time dealing with API. How to correctly called api which accept file input? The image is what the input I am supposed to parsed in according to swagger. I have also added the log for heroku and the error I am getting from React Native.
[image]
[image]
[image]

React Native Code

```
const getImg = async imageUrl => {
    const response = await fetch(imageUrl);
    const imageBlob = await response.blob();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(imageBlob);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const base64data = reader.result;
      setImgUrl(base64data);
    };
  };
const chooseFromLibrary = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: false,
    }).then(image => {
      console.log(image);
      console.log(image['mime']);
      getImg(image.path);
      hi();
    });
  };
const hi = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(
      'https://receipt-ocr-heroku.herokuapp.com/receiptOcr',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          file: imgUrl,

          
        }),
      },
    );
    console.log(response);
    let result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);
  };
```

FastAPI Python

```
@app.post("/receiptOcr")
async def main(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        image = await file.read()
        # image = cv2.imread(image)
        nparr = np.fromstring(image, np.uint8)
        img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.